# how to add dropdown control as a node to TreeView Conrol

Tags: asp.net, treeview, drop-down-menu

how can i add dropdown to treeview control.The dropdown contains 4 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the NodeTemplate to be a `dropdown list`

Example:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">
        <NodeTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Choice 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Choice 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Choice 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Choice 4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </NodeTemplate>
        <Nodes>
            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Node 1" Value="1" >
            <Nodes>
            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Child 1" Value="1"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
            </Nodes>
            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Node 2" Value="2">
            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Renders:

[image]

Comment: Is he even using Telerik controls??

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer hahaha I need to rest :( I read treeview and immediately associated with telerik because I've used them. Will delete my answer

Comment: I wouldn't delete it - might be useful for someone else coming along that may be using that control.